# Can I visually separate bits inside bit vector constants?

Tags: vhdl

Can I separate bits inside bit vector declarations to better differentiate them?
For example I have a 32 bit instruction like:

00000000000000000000000000000000

As you can see it's not as easy to look at is as with just 8 bits. So I want to write something like:

000000,00000,00000,00000,00000,000000

Tadaaa! much more readable. Is there a way to do this in VHDL?

Answer (score 3):

In a bit-string-literal and decimal-literal the underline character '_' gets removed and does not affect the value.

So writing 0000000_00000_000_0000_00_0 or "0000000_00000_000_0000_00_0" is allowed.

Comment: Thank you :) this i exactly what I was looking for quite a while now.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to consider is the `&` operator, used to concatenate several elements, even of different datatypes (with suitable conversions of course):

```
sig <= some_top_bits & "00" & some_other_bits & to_unsigned(some_integer, 4);
```